# Bulge effect in Affinity Designer

Tags: affinity-designer

I want to create this effect in Affinity Designer:

[image]

In Illustrator i go to effects>warp>bulge

[image]

Is there a buldge effect equivalent in affinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Envelope/Mesh warping does not (yet) exist in Affinity Designer. Here is a feature request for it:

https://affinity.serif.com/forum/index.php?/topic/6971-envelope-warping-object-distort-perspective-tool-or-fisheye-tool/

Oddly enough, it does exist in Affinity Photo: https://www.lynda.com/Affinity-Photo-tutorials/Distorting-Mesh-Warp/453344/473863-4.html

Comment: oh no! how come is this thing not available, this is basic!

Comment: My thinking: because Affinity Designer is actually focused on illustrators, not designers. This is despite the name. Kind of like how Adobe Illustrator is focused on designers, not illustrators. The great naming irony of software... perhaps.

Comment: And actually them guys did hear us... They have "Mesh warp/distort tool" on the 2017 road map. See here: https://affinity.serif.com/forum/index.php?/topic/842-affinity-designer-feature-roadmap/

Comment: @DerWOK, it's been on the roadmap since they first released a roadmap, during the initial beta release...

Comment: It's still in Feb 2020 nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Affinity Photo's Mesh Wrap tool for an Affinity Design file.
With the document open in AD click on the file menu, then click on "Edit in Photo…" AD will open the document in AP. Then select the layer you want to distort, and then click the Mesh Wrap tool. Be sure to do this as a last step because it does rasterize the shape. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Like Cris-Gato above has said, but you can actually start in designer then edit in Photo, then if you apply any of the live filters from the layers panel like "sphere" for example then go back to Designer they are now available in that layer and editable, yes in designer, I believe it's because it uses the same file type in all Affinity products.